# Is there an 8-bit code page (CP-####) such that every byte is defined?

Tags: python, codepages

I am currently trying to make a code for a data compression algorithm. My goal is to take a file and read it, convert it to its binary equivalent, and then store it into an output text file.

For example:
Lets say my *input* is "Hello World",

then what I want in my *output* is "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100".

This code does this successfully for most messages. However, I have a file with a neccessary byte of information that is "10000001". In CP-1252, this maps to an undefined character.

Is there an 8-bit code page that I can use in Line 9, Character 51 of my code that uses all 256 possible codes to avoid this error?

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

#makes a file with a unique timestamp in the name
stamp = now.strftime("%H%M%S")
f = open("requests" + str(stamp) + ".txt", "w")

#opens desired input file in read mode
text_file = open("videointxt", mode="r", encoding=None)
                                                  ^
#read whole file to a string
data = text_file.read()

#takes the message converts it to its binary equivakent, and then writes it to the output file
res = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in data)
print(res, file=f)


f.close
```

Comment: Your output is a string of ordinary ASCII `"1"`s and `"0"`s. It's not clear where you are having a problem with character sets.

Comment: Just to note, `encoding=None` doesn't "disable" decoding when you read from the file. It just tells `open` to use your platform's default encoding, which may not be what the file *actually* uses to encode the enclosed text. Also, if you want to read raw bytes, open the file in binary mode (`mode='rb'`) and interpret the bytes yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the code page per-se. Your problem is that you're trying to interpret the binary information into glyphs. In python3.x strings are Unicode. For Python to read in data as a string it needs to know the mapping of values to glyphs i.e. the encoding. If you just want to load raw data without interpreting it you probably want to preform a byte read and skip passing an encoding.

```py
- text_file = open("videointxt", mode="r", encoding=None)
+ text_file = open("videointxt", mode="rb")
```

The variable `text_file` will now be type bytes instead of type string so you'll need to change how you're interacting with it but this does mean that you don't need to mess with encodings until deciding how you want to display information to the screen.

Personally I'd suggest displaying output in hex instead of binary.

---

Please note that on disk text data is already a binary format. There are no storage gains to be had by storing the binary equivalent to disk. The act of converting from characters to binary and writing to disk is inverse of what happened when the file was read to begin with.

As @chepner says your code produces a string of '0', and '1' characters which will increase the total file size by a factor of 8.

If you're working at a linux terminal you can see this for yourself:

```py
# my_script.py
with open('tmp', 'rb') as f:
    data = file.read()
    print(''.join(format(i, '08b') for i in data))
```

```sh
$ echo -n 'a' > tmp
$ xxd -b tmp
00000000: 01100001                                               a
$ python my_script.py > tmp
$ xxd -b tmp
00000000: 00110000 00110001 00110001 00110000 00110000 00110000  011000
00000006: 00110000 00110001                                      01
```

Note how you've expanded the file size from 1 byte to 8, because instead of storing 'a' as 1 byte of data you're storing 8, instances of the characters '0', and '1'.

Comment: That's a *very* bad way of dealing with text. The bytes will be unusable until they're converted to text. When that happens the problem will be exactly the same - an encoding must be specified. Unless the text is displayed as a hex value, which is still a kind of encoding. If the file's encoding is known, it can be used in `open` as well as any other place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're 100% right. My interpretation of the OP is that they're wanting to read in a file, *"convert it to binary"* and write it back to disc. I think the core problem isn't whether the string is read as characters or binary, but thinking that string data on disk isn't already a binary format. I'd love to hear any suggestions about how I can better explain that. :)

Comment: The core reason I wanted to write the ASCII format of the original binary of the file was to then have python do bit manipulations to the now outputted file, then recompile the now manipulated ASCII binary file back into a regular binary file. This step to write the input file into an ASCII binary file is for a data compression algoithm to read through it.
However, I think if I just have the code just read the binary, break it into smaller chunks, put the chunks into a dictionary, then I think I can do the same thing without needing the convert into ASCII-binary step.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is at least one single-byte character set where every byte value is mapped: [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

It's a decent choice for visualizing binary data (e.g. in a hex editor). It has no newline character. But note that although it only lists 00 as a control character, many APIs will still interpret characters among 01-1f and 7f as control characters anyway, so use with caution.

I would not use it as a storage format though, base64 is much more appropriate for safely storing binary data in a string.

Comment: If someone knows of a better codepage for visualizing binary data, I'd like to know! There was a MSDN blog post where one was mentioned, but now I can't find it.